# How to use authorize.net in Android via phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

How to implement authorize.net in android via phonegap,i have found authorize.net plugins,i can't install anyone,it shows no plugin found:-

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: It's not possible,there is no any phonegap plugin for authorize.net.so i used android sdk and return transaction result to javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i created own custom plugin for communicating both Javascript and android code.

Now it's working for me.

Comment: Can you please share the plugin with others?

Comment: Can you share the plugin?